# selecting from data base according user inputs

Tags: oracle, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

servlets, oracle SQL developer .. i want to select data from database but accoeding to user inputs .. here is my code

```
public ResultSet f_items(Connection conn,String price) throws SQLException {
    String query = "select * from items where price=? ";
    Statement st=conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet set=st.executeQuery(query);
    return set;
}
```

the price is a column in the table ... but this code gives me an SQL exception which is

```
: ORA-01008: not all variables bound
```

any help ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not set the expected price on the statement. It should look sth. like this:

```
....
String query = "select * from items where price='" + price + "'";
ResultSet set=st.executeQuery(query);
```

**EDIT**: like Multisync suggested, but with an explanation :)

```
String query = "select * from items where price=? ";
PreparedStatement st=conn.prepareStatement(query);
st.setString(1, price);
ResultSet set=st.executeQuery(query);
```

Why is using a prepared statement better?

- concatenating user input into DB queries is [a recipe for disaster](http://xkcd.com/327/), known as SQL injection.
- methods of `PreparedStatement` like `setString` will escape the string value for you, preventing SQL injection.

Comment: i am getting that exception ": ORA-00904: "SINGLE": invalid identifier"

Comment: The meaning of the exception is that a column named 'SINLGE' is expected, but there is no such column in the table. Since you do not ask for the value of a specific column, this error should not occur. Are you absolutely sure that the exception is thrown by the line with the `executeQuery`? In order to exclude as much possibilities for a failure, change the `*` in the query to a column name that is guaranteed to exist, perhaps 'id'.

Comment: but SINGLE is a value in a column not column name

Comment: right, you need to escape the string value by hyphens. Please see edited answer.

Comment: OR even better, like Multisync suggested, use a prepared statement. See second edit.

Answer (score 0):

```
public ResultSet f_items(Connection conn,String price) throws SQLException {
    String query = "select * from items where price=? ";
    PreparedStatement st=conn.prepareStatement(query);
    st.setString(1, price);
    ResultSet set=st.executeQuery(query);
    return set;
}
```

Comment: what is the meaning of one in "st.setString(1, price);"

Comment: @yoyo riri The position of "?" in your query. It's better to use bindings whenever possible because this query will be prepared once on the database side and then will be reused many times (but with different params). So you'll economise on db resources.

Comment: @yoyo riri For example: "select * from items where id = ? and price=?" st.setInt(1, id); st.setString(2, price);

Comment: @yoyo By the way, you've accepted the answer without prepared statement - why?

Comment: @Multisync - the code you suggested was better than my concatenating solution. However, this was a [code-only answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272/is-there-any-benefit-to-allowing-code-only-answers-while-blocking-code-only-ques). This practice is commonly [discouraged on SO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140040/how-to-improve-low-quality-answers-consisting-of-only-a-code-block). If the OP does not know how to use statements, chances that he will understand the benefits of a prepared statement without any explanation are not very high.

Comment: My original answer used prepared statements, then I decided to 'tone it down' to the actual problem described by the OP and used a regular Statement. After seeing your answer, I decided to reintroduce PreparedStatement, but with an explanation. When my answer was accepted, it already had both variants.